# Регулярные выражения. Паттерн через переменную

Tags: python, re

Задача:
Пользователь вводит строку и ключевые слова. Программа должна найти эти слова в введённой строке и изменить их регистр на верхний.

```
import re

print("Поиск слова и верхний регистр")
user_string = input("Введите строку:").lower()
search_words = input("Введите слова через запятую:").replace(' ', '').lower()
search_words = search_words.replace(',', '|')
pattern = r'[search_words]'

new_string = re.sub(pattern, pattern.upper(), user_string)

print(new_string)
```

Полагаю что это достаточно лёгкий вопрос, но нет достаточного опыта с регулярными выражениями.
В строке с ключевыми словами через replace() отделил слова друг от друга через логический оператор 'или' ,чтобы в дальнейшем эту строку сделать паттерном для поиска каждого слова. Не знаю каким образом сделать именно этот момент.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не надо менять регистр входных строк, вместо этого `flags=re.IGNORECASE` указывает его игнорировать.

Все слова образца надо пропустить через [re.escape](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape).

Функция [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) умеет принимать лямбду вместо строки замены. Лямбда меняет регистр найденного фрагмента.

**NB**: слова заключены в скобки и обрамлены символами `\b` - обозначающими границу слова.

```
import re


print("Поиск слова и верхний регистр")
user_string = input("Введите строку:")
search_words = input("Введите слова через запятую:")

alternatives = '|'.join(re.escape(w.strip()) for w in search_words.split(','))
pattern = f'\\b(?:{alternatives})\\b'

new_string = re.sub(
    pattern,
    lambda m: m.group(0).upper(),
    user_string,
    flags=re.IGNORECASE
)

print(new_string)
```

Comment: +- разобрался в коде, но тут ещё не всё работает корректно. Если вводить строки или отельные буквы, то программа работает не совсем корректно.Допустим я ввожу в ключевые слова запрос рода "а, о, в". После этого обработанная строка будет выглядеть примерно: 
кОд рАбОтает не сОВсем кОрректнО.
Можете подсказать что с этим можно сделать?

Comment: Сейчас поднимается регистр для всех перечисленных букв. А как должно быть?

Comment: Нам же по условию задачи необходимо работать именно со словами, а не отдельными символами.

Comment: Добавил границы слов в образец.

Comment: Спасибо большое.